# mod_rewrite disallow call of subfolder

Tags: mod-rewrite

I am using 2 Domains like http://doma.in and http://domain.com

The shortning URL calls only generated URL's from my Script. All other calls from the shortning URL should be forwarded to the Main Domain. Thats why I have this small mod_rewrite Rule.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^doma.in [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**The Question**

I want to disallow calling subfolders from the shortning URL. Because the shortning URL can also generate Custom URLs like

http://www.nokia.com -> http://doma.in/nokia

If I would have a subfolder called **"nokia"** than it will not be forwarded to the target. Instead of to forward it is calling the subfolder.

To forward URLs over mod_rewrite is this Rule used.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-x
RewriteRule ^(.*) /redirect.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little unclear.

If you want the redirect to execute for /nokia even if you have a directory called /nokia, you need to remove the line:
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

What that condition says is "If the file path of the request is an existing directory, do not continue."

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The forward without !-d did not change anything. I dont have any idea how else I could forward to target instead to call the directory.